# Составить SQL-запрос для получения строк, значения которых идентичны переданной в запрос совокупности значений

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

Заголовок вопроса, возможно, не совсем точный и правильный, но у меня не получилось его сформулировать нормально.

Есть таблица из двух столбцов (например, заказы (orders) и типы товаров (products)):

| Orders | Products |
| --- | --- |
| o1 | p1 |
| o1 | p2 |
| o2 | p1 |
| o2 | p2 |
| o2 | p3 |
| o2 | p4 |
| o3 | p1 |
| o3 | p2 |
| o3 | p3 |

Заказы могут содержать разные типы товаров, которые, в свою очередь, могут присутствовать в разных заказах.

Нужно написать запрос, возвращающий только те заказы, типы товаров которых перечислены в запросе (в виде кортежа, например). Но есть пара условий, как в следующем примере.

Если я передаю в запрос значения (p1, p2, p3), то мне должны вернуться строки **только с заказом o3**, потому что *заказ o1 не сожержит товар типа p3*, а *в заказе o2 есть лишний товар типа p4*. То есть результат - три строки с заказом o3. Либо можно не возвращать строки с товарами, а просто вернуть значение o3.

**Вопрос**: как написать такой запрос, чтобы он был максимально оптимальным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT orders
FROM table
WHERE products IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3')
GROUP BY orders
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT products) = 3;
```

Если `(orders, products)` определено как UNIQUE, то DISTINCT можно убрать за ненадобностью.

Если нужны отдельные записи - использовать это как CTE либо подзапрос для отбора из второй копии таблицы.

---

Или можно воспользоваться оконной функцией:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(products) OVER (PARTITION BY orders) cnt
              FROM table
              WHERE products IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3') )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 3;
```

Это работает только когда `(orders, products)` определено как UNIQUE. ЕМНИП оконный COUNT(DISTINCT) не поддерживается.

---

> Ваш запрос отфильтрует столбец products по наличию p1, p2 и p3 и группировку применит к результату фильтрации. Под условие в having попадут o2 и o3. Условие задачи нарушается.

Как-то я просмотрел, что нужно не только наличие из списка, но и отсутствие не из списка. Тогда

```sql
SELECT orders
FROM table
GROUP BY orders
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT products) = 3
   AND NOT SUM(products NOT IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3'));
```

Comment: Ваш запрос отфильтрует столбец products по наличию p1, p2 и p3 и группировку применит к результату фильтрации. Под условие в having попадут o2 и o3. Условие задачи нарушается. Я в принципе решение этой проблемы и искал, заддавая вопрос. Мне изначально показалось, что Ваш ответ решил проблему, но оказалось не так.

Comment: @J.Doe Добавлено.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы нашел вариант, как можно решить поставленную задачу. Сначала нужно посчитать количество продуктов для всех заказов и оставить только те заказы, в которых находится интересующее количество продуктов. Затем фильтруем результат по наличию нужных продуктов в заказе.

```
WITH h_table AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        orders
    FROM table
    GROUP BY orders
    HAVING COUNT(products) = 3
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM h_table
JOIN table ON table.orders = h_table.orders
WHERE products IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3')
```